# How change JSON response result in POST request | DRF?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am little bit confused and need some advise how correctly organize view. In my Django REST Framework project I have pretty simple model and serializer.

**models.py**:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    body = models.TextField()
```

**serializers.py**:

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('id', 'body')
```

Lets say I have next data in database:

```
ID | BODY
-------------------------------------------------------------
1  | Aki doing his homework about japanese robot in library.
2  | All chapters are accompanied by necessary links.
3  | Japanese robot Aki doing a lot of tasks.
```

Right now I try to send `JSON` by `POST` request to `ArticleFilterView` controller:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '[
{
    "first": ["Aki", "robot"], 
    "second": ["doing", "library"]
}]'

http://localhost:8000/api/article/filter/
```

If any article has words "Aki" and "robot" in body field, I want to add that article to JSON response. In the same time I need to remove "doing" and "library" words from the text.

**Input:**

```
[{
    "fisrt": ["Aki", "robot"], 
    "second": ["doing", "library"]
}]
```

**Output:**

```
[
{"id": 1, "body": "Aki his homework about japanese robot in ."},
{"id": 3, "body": "Japanese robot Aki a lot of tasks."},
]
```

**views.py:**

```
class ArticleFilterView(APIView):
    parser_classes = (JSONParser,)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        # some code
        return Response({'received data': request.data})
```

**settings.py:**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ),
}
```

**urls.py:** (in the same directory where is `settings.py` file)

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/', include('article.urls')),
]
```

**article/urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(
        'article/filter/',
        ArticleFilterView.as_view(),
        name='article_filter',
    ),
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, this would work. (I'm only mentioning the logic, not exact code)

```
class ArticleFilterView(APIView):
    parser_classes = (JSONParser,)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        # some code
        return_data = {}
        if first got a match:
            return_data.update({'received data': request.data[0]['first']})
        elif second got a match:
            return_data.update({'received data': request.data[0]['second']})
        return_data.update({"search_result":your_serch_result})
        return Response(data=return_data)
```

**UPDATE**
Full implementation of view

```
from django.db.models import Q


class ArticleFilterView(APIView):
    parser_classes = (JSONParser,)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        for key, value in request.data.items():
            my_filter = Q()
            for search in value:
                my_filter &= Q(body__icontains=search)
            queryset = Article.objects.filter(my_filter)
            if queryset.exists():
                serializer = ArticleSerializer(queryset, many=True)
                return_data = {
                    "search_result": serializer.data,
                    "input_data": {key: value}
                }
                return Response(data=return_data)
        return Response({"message": "No data found"})
```

But, your input payload must be a `dict` like object as,

```
{
    "first": ["Aki", "robot"], 
    "second": ["doing", "library"]
}
```

**UPDATE-2**
Change `views.py` as,

```
from django.db.models import Q


class ArticleFilterView(APIView):
    parser_classes = (JSONParser,)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        my_filter = Q()
        for search in request.data.get('first'):
            my_filter &= Q(body__icontains=search)

            queryset = Article.objects.filter(my_filter)
            if queryset.exists():
                serializer = ArticleSerializer(queryset, many=True,context={"request":request})
                return_data = {
                    "search_result": serializer.data,
                    "input_data": {"first": request.data.get('first')}
                }
                return Response(data=return_data)
        return Response({"message": "No data found"})
```

and serializer as,

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('id', 'body')

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super().to_representation(instance)
        for input in self.context['request'].data.get('second'):
            data['body'] = data['body'].replace(input, "")
        return data
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177548/discussion-on-answer-by-jerin-peter-george-how-change-json-response-result-in-po).

Comment: Thank you very much @JerinPeterGeorge :)